# SOAP and REST Api can be implemented together

Tags: sabre

The main question aim is to know whether we can implement rest and soap api both api in same application. My clients want to go with bargain max finder and then proceed to booking & create pnr.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If the preference is REST, today there available Orchestrated Services to Book Air.

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/book/create_passenger_name_record/

That, technically there are not limitations in mixing the consumption of the Technologies, if there are certain services you are looking to consume only available in SOAP to the day.